# How can I load an existing Keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have been trying to load a Keras model from here: https://github.com/gitshanks/fer2013 (includes .json and the .h5) to test some part of my code with a existing facial recognition model before diving in training one. I have searched for different ways to do it but I cannot load it. I was wondering if it had something to do with different versions of Keras when the model was saved and when I am loading it.

I have tried two different things I found on google and here but I cannot load it.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json
json_file = open('fer.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("fer.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")
```

Error:

```
raceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[31], line 6
    loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\saving\legacy\model_config.py:109 in model_from_json
    return deserialize_from_json(json_string, custom_objects=custom_objects)

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\layers\serialization.py:270 in deserialize_from_json
    config = json_utils.decode_and_deserialize(

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\saving\legacy\saved_model\json_utils.py:78 in decode_and_deserialize
    return json.loads(

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py:370 in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py:337 in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py:355 in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
new_model = load_model('fer.h5')
new_model.summary()
```

This last one was successful in loading a model I created earlier and saved with model.save().

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[32], line 2
    new_model = load_model('fer.h5')

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70 in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py:567 in __init__
    fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr=swmr)

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py:231 in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)

  File h5py\_objects.pyx:54 in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

  File h5py\_objects.pyx:55 in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

  File h5py\h5f.pyx:106 in h5py.h5f.open

OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
```

Comment: You need to be precise on errors you get when loading this model.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the questions with the errors I get.

Comment: Here is a direct and correct link to download the json file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gitshanks/fer2013/master/fer.json

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided works for me, I can also see the model using `loaded_model.summary()`. In your case, most probably the model is saved in a directory other than your current working directory. Hence the Traceback responds with `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value` and `OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)`.

Possible workarounds include either including the entire path in your `json_file = open('fer.json', 'r')`, like:
`json_file = open('/home/dev/Downloads/fer.json', 'r')`.

Else, you can check your current directory using:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

and copy the downloaded model to the current working directory.

Later you can use `loaded_model.summary()` to view the architecture of your network.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have checked the current directory and it is not the problem, The line of code that gets the error is the model_from_json. When I print(loaded_model), I get this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-color-mode="auto" data-light-theme="light" data-dark-theme="dark" data-a11y-animated-images="system">
Maybe, it does not work with HTML?

Comment: @afernandezwer You downloaded the json file incorrectly, you downloaded some html, you need to click "raw" in github to get the plain json file.